# Matplotlib home button not working after fig.clear()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a found a case where home button of matplotlib does not work.

I built this tool for plotting data where the user can add/remove plots to the same figure.

The problem occurs when:

- Using toolmanager `plot.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'`. I use it for creating a custom toolbar.
- Using interactive mode `plot.ion()` and `fig.clear()`. I use it for the user to be able to modify its plots interactive way.

Below is the minimum code that shows the problem (it's not my original tool which is way too big to show here).

You have to use a debugger to stop the script and use the zoom and home button BEFORE using `fig.clear()`. Then, when you redraw on the same figure, home button does not work anymore.

If you comment `plot.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'`, everything works fine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import numpy as np
plot.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager' # This option is necessary to add a custom tool to the toolbar
    
# Fake data for testing
x = np.linspace( 0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
y = np.cos(x)

fig = plot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( x, y )
plot.ion()
plot.show()

pass # STOP here with debugger and use the zoom and home tools --> it works

fig.clear( keep_observers = True )

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( x, y )
plot.show()

pass # STOP here with debugger and use the zoom and home tools --> it does not work
```

Also, the backward and forward button do not work either. I want these buttons to keep working in this situation. Any idea how to fix this ?

EDIT:
It seems that there is no good solution to this issue so I had to code replacement tools for these default tools (home, backward, forward). Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

When you clear the figure with `fig.clear()` it removes all axis, but leaves the figure itself intact. You can completely close the figure and create a new one instead of clearing it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import numpy as np
plot.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager' # This option is necessary to add a custom tool to the toolbar
    
# Fake data for testing
x = np.linspace( 0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
y = np.cos(x)

fig = plot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( x, y )
plot.ion()
plot.show()

pass # STOP here with debugger and use the zoom and home tools --> it works

plot.close(fig)

fig = plot.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( x, y )
plot.show()

pass # it should work now
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  but the point is I don't want to close the figure. For the user experience of my tool, it's much better if the figure is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

You might try one of the techniques used in the animation tools. That is using the artist created by `ax.plot()` directly to control what's rendered. Here's an approach that works for the snippet you've provided.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import numpy as np
plot.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager' # This option is necessary to add a custom tool to the toolbar
    
# Fake data for testing
x = np.linspace( 0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
y = np.cos(x)

fig = plot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1 )
lc, = ax.plot( x, y )
plot.ion()
plot.show()

pass # STOP here with debugger and use the zoom and home tools --> it works


xdata, ydata = [], []
lc.set_data(xdata, ydata)

pass  # STOP here with debugger and use the zoom and home tools --> its blank but it works

lc.set_data(x, y)

pass # STOP here with debugger and it still all works.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree that this work. However, it does not fit with how this code is used in my tool. For instance, when you re-draw for the second time, if the data is different (for instance try with `x = np.linspace( 0, 4 * np.pi, 1000)` ), the home button zoom will remain on the old limits of the first plot and won't adjust to the new data. Also, in my tool, the user can add extra subplots, which I don't think can be managed without removing the first axe since add_subplot has to know the total number of subplots from the start.

Comment: I'm glad it answers your question, please don't forget to accept it. 
Since you're still having issues with your implementation you may need to ask another question. Note that from the mpl docs "Home always takes you to the first, default view of your data". Others have found some ways around this, like this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896580/matplotlib-hooking-in-to-home-back-forward-button-events
My advice is not to use the mpl interactive window like a full dashboard gui, rather make a simple gui in tk and use mpl for the plot rendering.